# Plane from 3 points- the determinant formula doesn't work

Tags: matrices, vectors, determinant, 3d, plane-geometry

A plane is specified as $(x, y, z)=(0, 1, 1)+\lambda(1, -1, 1)+\mu(2, -1,0)$, and I'm supposed to find the plane equation. Using the formula \begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
x-x_1 & y-y_1 & z-z_1\\
x_2-x_1 & y_2-y_1 & z_2-z_1\\
x_3-x_1 & y_3-y_1 & z_3-z_1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
\end{equation} should have been simple enough, but what I keep getting, (considering points 1, 2, and 3 as per the order in which they're specified in the plane equation);
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
x & y-1 & z-1\\
1 & -2 & 0\\
2 & -2 & -1\\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
\end{equation}
while the correct answer is this;
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
x & y-1 & z-1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
2 & -1 & 0\\
\end{vmatrix}
=0
\end{equation}

Can someone help me with where I went wrong?

Comment: Note that $(1,-1,1)$ and $(2,-1,0)$ are vectors used to define the plane, but they are NOT points in the plane. As points on the plane you shoud use $(0,1,1)+(1,-1,1)$ and $(0,1,1)+(2,-1,0)$.

Comment: That answers it, thanks.